# Use response data from a HTTP request to another one Azure

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm designing a Logic App in Azure, is there any way to make two HTTP request like this :
1. I'm calling my Identity Server 4 to get a new access token
2. I want to get the access token from the first request, put it to header and call .Net Core Api Endpoint with it?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, are we missing something?  The situation you describe is pretty basic.  What is the complication?

Comment: I didn't know how to get the response from the first HTTP request in Azure, i found the solution : with Parsed Json Action on Azure Logic app

Comment: Glad to see you solve it by yourself. You could post it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

per my understanding, you want to know how to get access_token value from a JSON object which comes from response of get token http request . 
I did a simple demo for you : 
[image]

The details of the post request : 
[image]

This is a simple request to get access token in Azure. the response will be :

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3600",
    "ext_expires_in": "3600",
    "expires_on": "1557995356",
    "not_before": "1557991456",
    "resource": "<-resource name->",
    "access_token": "<-value of access token->"
}
```

As you can see this logic app is triggered by http request and it will do a post request to get an JSON object which contains an access_token. And finally it will return the access_token value in response .

So the key here is how to config so that we can get access_token value from the JSON response of step2 .

Let's open logic app code view, find  "response" =>"body" and modify its value as : "@body('HTTP').access_token"

[image]

So that you can get the certain param from your JSON response of previous http request :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the response of the first request by using `Parsing JSON` action.
[image]